# How to add an non indexed field to SOLR Results

Tags: solr

I have a Chemical search application where we will execute a Molecular search using a standard molecule matching engine and retrieve the IDs of the chemical structures and the hit's score or Similarity value from the engine.
My application will then invoke a SOLR with the list of IDs retrieved from the engine. I want to add the hit's score to the results.
1. Can I simply add this calculated field to SOLR's results? How?
2. Could I implement a SIMILARITY function to supply it as the score instead of the score created by Lucene?
3. I want to order the results by the score. The molecule search can drive this can I tell SOLR to retain the order of the ids passed as the search query?
We are using SOLR 3.5. It is part of a stack provided by our vendor and cannot just upgrade it.
I'm thinking implementing a custom Search handler to do molecule pre-search and then search solr with the output.
I am very new to SOLR and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send IDs into Solr and then sorting by those same IDs, what do you actually need a Solr for? Or are you sub-selecting from those IDs afterwards using Solr query?

In any case, if your implementation allows you to change solrconfig.xml, you should be able to sneak a custom Request Handler in, which should allow you to build your pre- and post- processing. Here is [one somewhat relevant article](http://sujitpal.blogspot.ca/2011/02/solr-custom-search-requesthandler.html).

Regarding custom similarity, I am not sure you mean what you think you mean (custom Request Handler is a higher level intercept). However, if you do mean it, [Wiki discusses what is possible](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Similarity) before and after Solr 4.

Comment: Thanks. I already found that link it may actually let me do what I need. 
SOLR will hold our product data which will be returned to the calling JSP. 
In Molecule searching the similarity is usually the Tanimoto similarity between the query and the hit, although other indices can be used as well. End users expect to see their results sorted by that relevancy.

Comment: It seems that boosting the structure ids by the chemical search score (more or less, I had to amplify it) gave me most of what I needed. I used the example in the link to learn how to put the structure search score into the Solr output